# View loaded from NIB and displayed with addSubView not following constraints

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios6, autolayout

I have a view loaded quite simply:

```
self.splashView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DownloadingData"
                                                        owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
```

It's a full height 4" retina view in portrait mode with status bar, top bar and bottom bar set to none.  It has constraints such that an image is aligned along the bottom.  I use similar views within controllers elsewhere in the app and they resize into the available space (with NavigationBar and TabBar) absolutely fine.  However this view, loaded directly from a nib and then added appears to ignore the constraints.

The view is intended for use in all sorts of situations, e.g. with/without any combination of navigation bars/tab bars.

I've tried various combinations of `setNeedsLayout`, `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on splashView.  I have also tried calling `layoutSubviews` on the view itself.

Can anyone offer some advice?  In this instance should I be doing it another way?  With a viewController perhaps, or adding the constraints manually in code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I guess it was obvious really:

```
self.splashView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DownloadingData"
                                                 owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
[self.splashView setFrame:self.view.frame];
```

Then auto resize/constraints work as expected.

Comment: Why do you have to set frame? I'm having the same problem and I'd prefer to do everything in auto layout. Ya know?

Comment: I have no idea to be perfectly honest, it was quite a while back and I don't actually do it like that now.  Back then the constraint handling in IB was awful, it's now merely sufferable with some quirks.  Working with a similar setup in storyboard I don't have that problem, nor do I need to set the frame.  This whole question/answer could well have been a problem with my understanding of constraints and XCode/Interface Builder's poor handling of them (in 2012).

Comment: it's better to use bounds for child views i/e  self.splashView.frame = self.view.bounds